# How to implement drag and drop List composition UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am a newbie for web development, I need to build a list composition UI with some drag and drop features. I found the fiddel (http://jsfiddle.net/dkuntz2/28EH5/3/) which is a close match of my requirement.

HTML:

```
<div id="storyboard">
  <div id="clips"></div>

  <div id="timelineNcommands">
    <div id="timelineCommands"></div>
    <div id="timelineHolder">
      <div id="timeline"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<pre id="scratchpad"></pre>
```

CSS:

```
#storyboard #clips {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
}

#storyboard .clip {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #d4d0ad;
  border: 10px solid #d4d0ad;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
}

#storyboard .clip h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}

#storyboard .clip p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#storyboard #timelineNcommands {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  background: #f8f7f1;`enter code here`
  border: 5px solid #dddabe;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#storyboard #timelineNcommands #timelineHolder {
  margin-left: -5px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

#storyboard #timelineNcommands #timeline {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#timeline").sortable({
    scroll: true,
    axis: 'x',
  })

  $("#timeline").on('sortreceive', function(event, ui) {
    setTimelineWidth(0);
  });

  $("#timeline").on('sortover', function(event, ui) {
    setTimelineWidth(70);
  })

  var clipNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  

  $.each(clipNums, function(i, num) {
    var div = $("<div/>", {
      class: 'clip',
      id: 'clip-' + num
    }).html(
      "<h2>" + num + "</h2>"
    )

    div.appendTo('#clips')
    div.draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      scroll: false,
      helper: "clone",
      connectToSortable: "#timeline",
      containement: '#storyboard',

      helper: function() {

        $("#storyboard").append(
          '<div id="clone" class="clip">' + 
          $(this).html() + '</div>'
        );

        return $("#clone");
      }
    })  
  })
})

function setTimelineWidth(extra) {
  if ($("#timelineNcommands").width() < ($("#timeline").sortable('toArray').length * 70) + extra) {      
    $("#timeline").width(($("#timeline").sortable('toArray').length * 70) + extra + "px")
    $("#scratchpad").html(($("#timeline").sortable('toArray').length * 70) + extra + "px")
  }
  else
    $("#timeline").width("220");
}
```

I badly stuck on getting the list of items dropped and their order after composing...

and any guide on "how to use this jsfiddle UI in asp.net applications" would be really helpful..

Comment: Are you sure you are newbie??

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you the right answer for this example but, you can use the serialize method to get the correct order of your items and this is the proper way to achieve it. However, the serialize method only works if the sortable list's children `id="key_value"`, i.e. `id="item_1"`, where "item" is the key and "1" the value. In this example, I've noticed you can have multiple clones of the same item so having same ids (2 items in the timeline having id=item_3), it's impossible.

I'm also a newbie in jquery but, I had the same issue in my project and solved using serialize method.